# Do I have to make a new activity to use a settings fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following the preference fragment solution in this page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Here is the code used:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
...
}

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

This solution works but before I did this I tried something different.

At first, I tried opening the Settings without using SettingsActivity. I wanted to switch the my main fragment in my main activity with Settings Fragment as such (this code is inside my MainActivity file):

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This R.id.container is the FrameLayout in my activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

</FrameLayout>
```

This approach doesn't seem to work, why? The Settings fragment goes over the current fragment since the current fragment is not replaced.

What would be the performance penalties if I choose to make a new activity with the menu fragment instead?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine but you can try this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Where `android.R.id.content` gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name, type or ID.

Comment: I tried that solution but my settings fragment still overlaps with my main fragment.